# Execution failed for task ':gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'

Tags: reactjs, kotlin

React native using the cli, created a project, configured Android Studio, but when compiling the project I get this error

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

I searched the floor of the Internet forums and helped people in each topic, but it's like I have another universe, please help me solve

build.gradle
`    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-      projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}`
```

settings.gredle
`rootProject.name = 'MyReactNativeProject' apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings) include ':app' includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')`

Version JAVA JDK - 21

I looked through many solutions, but not one of them did not help